# Cannot implicitly convert type 'DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandsNextExtension' to 'DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandsNextConfiguration'

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

I try to make a discord bot in c# with plugin d# and I have this error that shouldn't exist I watch a tutorial and I copy the code so it should work

```
 public class Bot
{
    public DiscordClient Client { get; private set; }
    public CommandsNextConfiguration Commands { get; private set; }
    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var config = new DiscordConfiguration
        {

        };

        Client = new DiscordClient(config);

        Client.Ready += OnClientReady;
        var commandsConfig = new CommandsNextConfiguration
        {

        };

        Commands = Client.UseCommandsNext(commandsConfig);
        



    }

    private Task OnClientReady(object sender, ReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> public CommandsNextConfiguration Commands { get; private set; }     //not working
>
> public CommandsNextExtension Commands { get; private set; }   // is true its working

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Commands = Client.UseCommandsNext(commandsConfig);
```

with

```
CommandsNextExtension commandsNextExtension = 
Client.UseCommandsNext(commandConfig);
Commands = commandsNextExtension;
```

This worked for me